# Do norm-preserving linear transforms exist that do not preserve angle?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for an example of a linear transform that preserves norm but does not preserve angle. Do such transforms exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Every linear isometry is angle-preserving. To see this, we have that

$\displaystyle \frac{\langle v, w\rangle}{\|v\|\|w\|} = \frac{\langle Tv, Tw \rangle}{\|Tv\|\|Tw\|}$. The denominators are equal from the isometry, and the numerators are equal because isometries preserve inner products. To see this, use the polarization identity that $\langle v,w \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\|v+w\|^2 - \|v-w\|^2)$ and then use the fact that $\|Tv\| = \|v\|$. I'll leave that to you.